# Delphi TBytesField SetData

Tags: delphi

In a table, I have a TBytesField with size 60. When a record is created with this field set to nil, I want to set its value to an array of bytes like `[0,0,0.....0]`.  I am using this code:

```
var
  ar : array of byte;
begin
  if ByteField.AsBytes = nil then
  begin
    SetLength(ar, ByteField.Size);
    ByteField.SetData(ar, True);
  end;
end;
```

Although `ar` has all bytes zero, I see that the field takes these values instead:

```
[17,32,0,0,0,0,0,0,48,192,182,1,0...0]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `SetData()` directly. Use the `AsBytes` property:

```
var
  ar : TBytes;
begin
  if ByteField.IsNull then
  begin
    SetLength(ar, ByteField.Size);
    ByteField.AsBytes := ar;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This was my first approach but i received the message "invalid argument" at  bytesFiled.asBytes := ar (at the variants unit executing the procedure TranslateResult(AResult: HRESULT) )

Comment: I don't understand. [The `AsBytes` property](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.DB.TField.AsBytes) is read/write and operates on `TBytes` values. Assigning a `TBytes` variable to a `TBytes` property should not be involving anything in the `Variants` unit at all.

Comment: @JimPapas Please provide a callstack for when the error occurs, so that it can be determined why TranslateResult is being called.

Comment: The problem occurs when i call the BeforePost event where I try to fill the TBytes field with zero values.
the callstack is this :
:75bcb802 KERNELBASE.RaiseException + 0x62
System.Variants.TranslateResult(???)
System.Variants.VarResultCheck(???)
System.Variants.VarArrayAsPSafeArray(???)
System.Variants.VarArrayHighBound(Unassigned,1)
:00436b85 VarResultCheck + $9
Data.DB.TDataSet.DataConvert($38E92C0,???,???,True)
:0088e651 TABSDataSet.DataConvert + $91
:0088e6ad TABSDataSet.DataConvert + $41
... continue at next message

Comment: ... 
Data.DB.TDataSet.SetFieldData(???,(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),False)
Data.DB.TField.SetData((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),True)
Data.DB.TField.SetAsBytes(???)
myUnit.TForm34.MyQueryBeforePost($41B3120)
Data.DB.TDataSet.DoBeforePost
Data.DB.TDataSet.Post

Comment: I solve my problem altering the TbytesField to TBLOBfield and accessing it asBytes 

eg. i can do myBLOBfield.value := ar
or ar := myBLOBfield.value